# React unsubscribe a listener from anywhere in the app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need help extracting a database listener function into its own callable function so I can unsubscribe from it. Here is what I have:

```
const reroute = (user) => {
  // A function to route user based on its state values
};

export function AuthenticateUser() {
  const user = useStore((state) => state.user);
  const setUser = useStore((state) => state.setUser);
  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribe;
    function setupUser(userDetails) {
      Analytics.setUserId(userDetails!.id);
      setUser(userDetails);
    }
    if (!user) {
      // LISTENER 1 : Authenticate user. We unsubscribe from this listener in the cleanup function.
      unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((authenticatedUser) => {
        if (authenticatedUser) {
          const uid = authenticatedUser.uid;
          const db = firebase.firestore();
          // LISTENER 2: This is the listener I need to be able to unsubscribe from wherever I need.
          const unsubscribeUserUpdates = db.collection("users").doc(uid)
            .onSnapshot(
              async (doc) => {
                // onSnapshot listener will fire this whenever something updates on the server
                const documentData = doc.data();
                const userData = {
                  id: doc.id,
                  ...documentData,
                };
                setupUser(userData);
                setLoadingUser(false);
                reroute(userData);
              },
              (error) => {
                console.log("error", error);
                alertMessage("danger", "User authentication failed", error.message);
                reportError("GQL_getOrCreateUser", error);
              }
            );
        } else {
          // No authenticated user
          setLoadingUser(false);
          reroute(null);
        }
      });
    }
    return () => {
      unsubscribe?.();
      // unsubscribeUserUpdates?.(); << If I run this, then the listener will be terminated, but I don't want to terminate it here.
    };
  }, [GQL_getOrCreateUser, setLoadingUser, setUser, user]);
}
```

I load `AuthenticateUser` into my react navigation `index.ts`

```
export default function Navigation() {
  AuthenticateUser();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    ...
```

I have a Sign Out function here which fires on button click that should sign the user out and terminate the unsubscribeUserUpdates listener

```
export default function AccountNavigator() {
  const setUser = useStore((state) => state.setUser);
  function signOut() {
    setUser(null);
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }
  return (
    <AccountStack.Navigator>
      ...
```

I want to be able to terminate the `unsubscribeUserUpdates` listener, but I think that for that I need to have it as a callable function. I tried extracting it to a `useCallback` hook, but got errors.

Could someone **please** let me know, with code example, what to do to be able to load the listener in `AuthenticateUser` and stop it anywhere I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a new useEffect for unmounting purpose. Empty dependencies make the useEffect work as componentDidMount and returning that makes it componentWillUnmount

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = someAuthStuff();
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Correct. This is the solution, also explained in more detail here: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/firebase-firestore-database-realtime-updates-with-react-hooks-useeffect-346c1e154219. I would only edit the deps array to accomplish what I wanted - set a stateful flag when logging out.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize a variable

on useEffect try this:

mounted = true
...
mounted && fun();
return () => (mounted = false);